# How to extend datamodel in LINQPad using partial classes?

Tags: c#, datacontext, linqpad, partial-classes

In a C# program, one can extend a class in a generated datamodel by using partial classes (because the generated classes are marked partial, how nice of them).

But I want to do the same in LINQPad. How do I do that ? I can't see the generated datamodel, so I don't know what namespace and classname to use.

Comment: What datamodel are you referring to? Do you simply want to use a partial class in LINQPad?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel When connecting LINQPad to a database, an EF datacontext is generated automatically with all tables. He wants to add properties or methods to one of the generated classes. In a normal Visual Studio solution you can do this by adding a partial class declaration alongside the generated class, he's asking how that can be done in LINQPad for the same situation.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that can't be done.

The reason is that the datacontext and related types are defined in a separate assembly from your query.

You can verify this by running the following [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program, substituting the "apartments" type with a type from your database.

```
void Main()
{
    typeof(apartments).Assembly.GetName().Dump();
    GetType().Assembly.GetName().Dump();
}
```

Comment: Possibly the point is if the code in "My Extensions" and the generated datacontext can see each other, so to speak. But I still need to know something about the names, where things are put.

Comment: Seems like it can't be done. But wouldn't it be nice if one could ... hopefully the LINQPad guy(s) will notice this :)

Comment: Aside from hoping that, you may want to check if a similar idea is already present on http://linqpad.uservoice.com/.

Comment: I couldn't find one, so I added it here: http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6211427-add-a-way-of-extending-the-autogenerated-dataconte  Feel free to vote it up, if you like it :)

Comment: There's another difficulty: LINQPad doesn't compile the typed datacontext assembly from C# code. It generates it directly using Reflection.Emit.